# UITableView performing row deletion and insertion in a cascading animation manner

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiviewanimation

I am interested in deleting a batch of rows from a `UITableView` using the animation `tableView.deleteRows(at: [singleIndexPath], with: .automatic)`. However, my goal is to cascade the deletion animation so that they happen in a **cascading animated** manner, so that rather than the entire batch of rows being removed, the animnation will show them removed one after another.

I discovered a helpful `UITableView` extension where I get a completion block after an animation is finished, as such:

```
extension UITableView {

    /// Perform a series of method calls that insert, delete, or select rows and sections of the table view.
    /// This is equivalent to a beginUpdates() / endUpdates() sequence,
    /// with a completion closure when the animation is finished.
    /// Parameter update: the update operation to perform on the tableView.
    /// Parameter completion: the completion closure to be executed when the animation is completed.

    func performUpdate(_ update: ()->Void, completion: (()->Void)?) {

        CATransaction.begin()
        CATransaction.setCompletionBlock(completion)

        // Table View update on row / section
        beginUpdates()
        update()
        endUpdates()

        CATransaction.commit()
    }

}
```

My problem is figuring out how to utilize the block **automate** the animation of the row deletion (and later, row insertion). Right now, the following example code with two row `IndexPath`s still has animation occurring at the same time, which is not my goal.

```
    let singleIndexPath = IndexPath(row: 0, section: 0)
    let anotherIndexPath = IndexPath(row: 1, section: 0)

    self.tableView.performUpdate({

        self.tableView.deleteRows(at: [singleIndexPath, anotherIndexPath], with: .automatic)
        self.tableView.insertRows(at: [singleIndexPath, anotherIndexPath], with: .left)
        //Happening at the same time, which is not what I want
    }, completion: {

    })
```

Any tip is much appreciated.

Comment: Wouldn't you have to put the each index path you wish to delete inside the update handler of a separate call to `performUpdate`?

Comment: @paulvs Yes, but that wouldn't be automated or based on the number of rows I have. I could hardcode the rows but it would be ineffective.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Cascade Table View Row Deletion**

**Usage:**

```
let indexPathsToDelete = [IndexPath(row: 1, section: 0), IndexPath(row: 4, section: 0), IndexPath(row: 6, section: 0)]
 deleteRowsAt(indexPaths: indexPathsToDelete, in: tableView)
```

**Code:**

```
func deleteRowsAt(indexPaths: [IndexPath], in tableView: UITableView) {
    var state = (0 ..< tableView.numberOfSections).map {
        Array(0 ..< tableView.numberOfRows(inSection: $0))
    }

    func cascadeDeleteAt(indexPath indexPathToDelete: IndexPath) {

        // Get the current row for the index path we wish to delete.
        // It could be diffrent to its original index path if other rows have been deleted.
        guard let currentRow = state[indexPathToDelete.section].index(of: indexPathToDelete.row) else { return }

        let currentIndexPath = IndexPath(row: currentRow, section: indexPathToDelete.section)
        print(currentIndexPath)

        // --- IMPLEMENT THE DELETION FROM YOUR DATA SOURCE ---
        source.remove(at: currentIndexPath.row)


        state[indexPathToDelete.section].remove(at: currentIndexPath.row)

        tableView.performUpdate({
            tableView.deleteRows(at: [currentIndexPath], with: .left)
        }, completion: {
            guard var idx = indexPaths.index(of: indexPathToDelete) else { return }
            idx += 1
            if idx < indexPaths.count {
                let nextIndexPathToDelete = indexPaths[idx]
                cascadeDeleteAt(indexPath: nextIndexPathToDelete)
            }
        })
    }

    if let indexPath = indexPaths.first {
        cascadeDeleteAt(indexPath: indexPath)
    }
}
```

When deleting rows in a cascade way (i.e. deleting one row at a time instead of all rows at once), the tricky parts are that:

1. After deleting a row, other indices (index paths and also indices into data sources) don't point to where they used to.
2. The function `performUpdate` needs to be called from within a recursive function to allow for the next row to be deleted only after the current row has deleted.

Comment: This is really fantastic. I was trying to figure out a recursive solution to this and encountered exactly the issue you mentioned, where is that IndexPaths don't point to where they used to. You managed to solve this elegantly. Thank you!